# replacing all items with str.replace() with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I want to have a function that has an  input array, containing all the words that need to be removed from a string and I am having trouble achieving this.

I know that if I wanted to do that with plain text it would be

```
string = string.replace(/"word"/g, "");
```

but I want to do it with a function like below,

```
   function removeFromString(string, toRemove){
     for(var i = 0 ; i <  toRemove.length; i++){
     string = string.replace(/<tr>/g, "");
     string = string.replace(/<\/tr>/g, "");
     }

     return string;
    }

  var remove = new Array();
      remove[0] = '<tr>';
      remove[1] = '</tr>';

 removeFromString(string, remove)
```

What I've tried,

adding the slashes and g to the variable on declaration like so,

```
  remove[0] = '/<tr>/g';
  remove[1] = '/</tr>/g';
```

Adding the slashes and g next to variable in my function like so,

```
string = string.replace(/toRemove[i]/g, "");
```

but none seem to do the trick,

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

many thanks!

Comment: Your function is passed the value `remove`, but you are using a variable called `toRemove` in the loop, which isn't defined.

Comment: Aren't your slashes wrong? The character to escape is "\" not "/"

Comment: helpful tip -  be careful in IE less than 9 working with html from the DOM....  tags get converted to uppercase by browser. Using a lowercase regex pattern won't match

Comment: apologies, The above code is the code that is in my script.

Comment: thanks  charlietfl , although I'm using node.js so hopefully this should be ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the replace expression as a string and not as an expression object.
For example `"/</tr>/g"` is a string but `/</tr>/g` is a regular expression.

```
function removeFromString(s, toRemove){
  for(var i = 0, l = toRemove.length; i <  l; ++i){
    s = s.replace(toRemove[i], "");
  }

  return s;
}

var remove = [];
// These are regular expressions
// it's best to create them only once and reuse them
remove[0] = /<tr>/g;
remove[1] = /<\/tr>/g;

removeFromString(string, remove);
```